# Fix the AxisHelper at Left-Bottom of canvas in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am using AxisHelper which is available in Three.js. It works fine when I keep it at center of the canvas (0,0,0). But if I move it to the left-bottom of the page it does not work properly. i.e when I rotate the model the AxisHelper also gets rotated about (0,0,0). Please send your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you re-position it? How about showing your code so we don't need to guess?

Comment: this.axisHelper.position.set( -200, -200, 0 ); But I am planning to create a new renderer for axishelper. will this solve my problem?